# How to grab just element id - using Selenium WebDriver 2

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

EDIT:
I also tried this

```
 var webElements1 = (Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_lstCategory']//input"))).ToList();
```

I get the empty Text

I am trying to find a way to grab just ID from the list i am getting and below is my code and a print shot of my screen.

//WebDriver getting a list of Text

the below code returns me the correct number of records but it just give me the `Text` but I am after `Text` and `Id` of an particular `Text`

I tried this:

```
var webElements1 = (Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_lstCategory']/tbody/tr/td/span"))).ToList();
```

this

```
var webElements2 = (Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_lstCategory']/tbody/tr/td"))).ToList();
```

and this...

```
var webElements3 = (Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_lstCategory']"))).ToList();
```

the all code of line gives me the correct returns but without Id.

Here is the print screen of my page:

[image]

Comment: When you mean ID, you mean what? The actual ID of the control (ctl00_etc) or the text itself? ('Item 1', 'Item 2' etc?)

Comment: actual id of the control

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After getting all the elements using below method, run in loop to get all element's ids:

```
List<WebElement> element = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Control1_lstCategory']//input")));

for(WebElement ele:elements)
{

        ele.getAttribute("id");     // for getting id of each element

        ele.getText();              //for getting text of each element

}
```

Comment: I am getting the text from `webElement1` and Id from `webElement4` but what is the best of to merge togather?

Comment: I didn't get whats your requirement? If you want to run in loop that List either you can get all element texts or ids . You want to get some element id, some element text means You need to use some condition statements inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

1) i'll try to share the idea of the approach I would choose to resolve your issue:

```
getElementsByTagName('input');//returns array of elements
```

2) using js executor get element's attribute , ID in particular, iterating through the whole array  returned by  getElementsByTagName('input') and getting theirs IDs.
//sample of code I used to find color attribute:

```
public String jsGetColor(String cssSelector){

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append("var x=$(\'"+css+"\');");
    stringBuilder.append("return x.css('color')");
    String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
    return res;

}
```

this is simply my assumtion how it be possible to try. hope it somehow helps you)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one id:

```
String id = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Your text')]")).getAttribute("id");
```