# Retrieve ID of any element using webdriver in python given value of the element

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am using selenium to record testcases in firefox. It records a button click/or any action for that  matter like below,

```
driver = self.driver
driver.get(self.base_url + "/")
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00__mainContent_lnkforgotpassword").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("ctl00__mainContent_ucForgotPassword1_btnNext").click()
```

Here the driver makes use of the find_element_by_id method to access the element and it works great.

But my requirement is to find this Id given just the text of that element,
like -

If **Forgot Password** is a link and I want to retrieve the **ID** of this link,
I would modify the about code as,

```
driver.find_element_by_id(getID("Forgot Password")).click().
```

So is there a way to write **getId()** function so as to retrieve the **ID** of the link **Forgot Password** *(Or Id of some Label/Button in other cases)* from the current open page?

Answer (score 13):

There is no way to retrieve the ID (or any attribute) directly the way you mentioned.

But, you can find any attribute/property of a web element once you find that web element only.

do as follows:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Forgot Password") / returns Web Element, store it in some variable.
print elem.get_attribute("id")
print elem.get_property("id") // or use get_property
```

Reference:

1. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement

Comment: That works fine for links. What about any other element, like a button, label,etc

Comment: same way you did for link text. First, identify the element using one of its attributes (class, text, link text, name etc.) then you can retrieve ID from that Web Element if present.

Comment: find_element_*() API returns **WebElement**, which you can use to retrieve properties/attributes of the web element using WebElement API. Added reference URL for WebElement API in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps you need to do:
1. Get the element by link text
2. From that element get the attribute value of id.

You can try something similar to the below code to create your function:
(Note: Below code is JAVA, you would need to write the similar python code)

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Forgot Password"));
ele.getAttribute("id");
```

Below links will help as a reference:

[How to grab just element id - using Selenium WebDriver 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516542/how-to-grab-just-element-id-using-selenium-webdriver-2)

http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/01/how-to-locate-element-by-link-text-or.html